# Cannot use css() on dynamically created div in custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have recently taken up learning how to make a jQuery plugin. This is my first attempt at just creating something that is very simple. I am still relatively new to jQuery and have come into a bit of a bind when it comes to selecting dynamically created content. In this scenario I am attempting to select a `div` I created within the plugin.

I have made a jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/eeb57n88/).

I have perused many posts about selecting dynamically created `div`'s and most of them are solved either using `on` or a callback function. And I am not sure that those can be applied in this situation.

I think the issue occurs at this point in the code:

```
            $element.append("<div class=\"gifLoader\"></div>");
            $gifLoader = $element.find('.gifLoader');
            $gifLoader.css("bacground-image", "url(\"" + plugin.settings.gifSrc + "\")");
            plugin.settings.callback.call(this);
```

Is there some way I can use a callback function like you would with methods like `fadeTo`? Also, if anyone cares to comment. I would really appreciate some feedback on the layout of my plugins. I don't fully comprehend what it is I am doing when making a plugin, I am just hoping to learn how to use Javascript and jQuery without the coding looking so clunky. (Before I just had anonymous functions within anonymous functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one typo, and one error: `bacground-image` => `background-image`, and `src()` => `url()`

Change

```
$gifLoader.css("bacground-image", "src(\"" + plugin.settings.gifSrc + "\")");
```

To

```
$gifLoader.css("background-image", "url(\"" + plugin.settings.gifSrc + "\")");
```

Comment: This worked in jsFiddle, but it does not work when it is run in it's own browser window. Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: @MowgliB did you fix both typos (src and bacground)?

Comment: Palm to face. I hate how long I wasted staring at the screen over this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a dynamic element using javascript or jquery, that element does not reflect in your DOM straight away. If you take a look into the HTML that is generated using the developer tools you'd find before: and after: tags appended with your HTML.

The best way to realize the problem is to either specify the background-image when you are creating the div like:

```
$("#element").append("<div class='gifLoader' style='background-image: url('" + plugin.settings.gifSrc + "')'></div>");
```

Otherwise if you are looking to change the background-image on some kind of user interaction, you can go for this:

```
$("#element").append("<div class='gifLoader' id='someID' someEvent='transform(someID)'></div>");
```

And then have function transform() defined somewhat like:

```
function transform(elementID) {
    $("#" + elementID).css("background-image", "some image URL");
}
```